# Battery voltage measurement with voltage divider

Tags: battery, voltage-divider

I am using the following circuit to measure the Li-ion 3.7V battery capacity.

[image: Setup for 3.7V Batteries]

*Figure 1 – Schematic for 3.7 V batteries.*

This setup works fine for the 3.7V batteries.

To be able to measure 9V batteries, I modified the circuit with a voltage divider so that the Arduino sees max 5v at the analog input. However Arduino reports 0V. I have measured the output of voltage divider with a DMM and it shows 5V. I wonder why doesn't Arduino report the correct voltage. Could you please help me fix it?

[image: Modified schematic for 9 V batteries which doesn't work]

*Figure 2 – Modified schematic for 9 V batteries which doesn't work.*

My code:

```cpp
#include "LCD5110_Graph.h"
LCD5110 myGLCD(5, 6, 7, 9, 8); // Setup Nokia 5110 Screen SCLK/CLK=5, DIN/MOSI/DATA=6, DC/CS=7, RST=9 Chip Select/CE/SCE=8,
extern uint8_t SmallFont[];
extern uint8_t MediumNumbers[];

#define gatePin 10
#define highPin A0
#define lowPin A1

boolean finished = false;
int printStart = 0;
int interval = 5000; // Interval (ms) between measurements

float mAh = 0.0;
float shuntRes = 1.0; // In Ohms – Shunt resistor resistance
float voltRef = 4.71; // Reference voltage
float current = 0.0;
float battVolt = 0.0;
float shuntVolt = 0.0;
float battLow = 2.9;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long millisPassed = 0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Battery Capacity Checker v1.1");
    Serial.println("battVolt current mAh");

    pinMode(gatePin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(gatePin, LOW);

    myGLCD.InitLCD(); // initialize LCD with default contrast of 70
    myGLCD.setContrast(68);
    myGLCD.setFont(SmallFont); // Set default font size. tinyFont 4×6, smallFont 6×8, mediumNumber 12×16, bigNumbers 14×24
    myGLCD.clrScr();

    myGLCD.print("Battery", CENTER, 0);
    myGLCD.print("Check", CENTER, 12);
    myGLCD.print("Please Wait", CENTER, 24);
    myGLCD.print("AdamWelch.Uk", 8, 40);
    myGLCD.update();
    delay(2000);
    myGLCD.clrScr();
}

void loop()
{
    battVolt = analogRead(highPin) * voltRef / 1024.0;
    shuntVolt = analogRead(lowPin) * voltRef / 1024.0;

    if (battVolt >= battLow && finished == false)
    {
        digitalWrite(gatePin, HIGH);
        millisPassed = millis() – previousMillis;
        current = (battVolt – shuntVolt) / shuntRes;
        mAh = mAh + (current * 1000.0) * (millisPassed / 3600000.0);
        previousMillis = millis();

        myGLCD.clrScr();
        myGLCD.print("Discharge", CENTER, 0);
        myGLCD.print("Voltage:", 0, 10);
        myGLCD.printNumF(battVolt, 2, 50, 10);
        myGLCD.print("v", 77, 10);
        myGLCD.print("Current:", 0, 20);
        myGLCD.printNumF(current, 2, 50, 20);
        myGLCD.print("a", 77, 20);
        myGLCD.printNumI(mAh, 30, 30);
        myGLCD.print("mAh", 65, 30);
        myGLCD.print("Running", CENTER, 40);
        myGLCD.update();

        Serial.print(battVolt);
        Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print(current);
        Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.println(mAh);

        delay(interval);
    }
    if (battVolt < battLow)
    {
        digitalWrite(gatePin, LOW);

        finished = true;

        if (mAh < 10)
        {
            printStart = 40;
        }
        else if (mAh < 100)
        {
            printStart = 30;
        }
        else if (mAh < 1000)
        {
            printStart = 24;
        }
        else if (mAh < 10000)
        {
            printStart = 14;
        }
        else
        {
            printStart = 0;
        }

        myGLCD.clrScr();
        myGLCD.print("Discharge", CENTER, 0);
        myGLCD.print("Voltage:", 0, 10);
        myGLCD.printNumF(battVolt, 2, 50, 10);
        myGLCD.print("v", 77, 10);
        myGLCD.setFont(MediumNumbers);
        myGLCD.printNumI(mAh, printStart, 21);
        myGLCD.setFont(SmallFont);
        myGLCD.print("mAh", 65, 30);
        myGLCD.print("Complete", CENTER, 40);
        myGLCD.update();

        delay(interval * 2);
    }
}
```

Circuit with modifications

[image: Schematic for 9 V Batteries]

*Figure 3 – Schematic for 9 V batteries.*

Comment: Why such tiny resistor values?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't the correct schematic. I have updated the post with the correct one. I suppose you were referring to the voltage divider resistors?

Comment: Actually, ignore that - I was looking at the resistors wrong. The small ones are current sense and load, not the battery divider.

Comment: A load of 4.3ohm on a 9volt battery draws 2amps???

Comment: Yes that's indeed high so I am planning to use Rload = 10 ohm. My 9V nominal Li-ion battery has max voltage of 8V so with a total 11 ohm resistance the current will be limited around 819 mA. Since the resistors can take upto 10 W so it should be fine .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes because you are powering your load through the voltage divider you use for reading your battery voltage.

You cannot do high-side current reading like that with a voltage higher than the ADC voltage. Instead you need to do the current sensing *before* your voltage divider and *then* divide that result down again.

Your circuit should look more like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv81u4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have uploaded a new schematic and I hope I have incorporated your suggestion correctly. Can you please have a look? :)